# Can I compare two DVs with a paired t-test when originally there were different groups?

Tags: t-test, assumptions

Originally, my 42 participants were divided in two groups based on the language of the questionnaire they filled in.

There are two dependent variables, Total number of option A and Total number of option B. I want to compare these two variables without making a distinction between language version.

The paired samples t-test does what I need, but can I use it if the data was originally gathered from participants in different groups?

Comment: Are "option A" and "option B" two different answers to the same question or are they corresponding responses to two different questions?

Comment: For each question, participants could choose between option A or B. It was a linguistic questionnaire in which participants chose a preferred interpretation of ambiguous sentences. Each ambiguity could be solved in 2 ways, and option A and B each represented one of those ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you know or are willing to assume that the language difference is irrelevant *for that particular question*,  I can see no problems in what you propose.  If that assumption about irrelevance of language differences is acceptable, is not a statistics question, it must be defended on subject-matter grounds.